# Why would all our CLOSE_WAIT connections have 24 bytes in the receive queue?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, tcp, apache-httpd

We have an Apache reverse proxy that is having connectivity issues with the back-end. This results in timeout errors such as this:

```
[Thu Apr 21 12:12:26.031207 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 64620:tid 139950024484608] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.27.27:31458] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server backend.example.com:443, referer: https://frontend.example.com/webapp
[Thu Apr 21 12:12:26.031238 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 64620:tid 139950024484608] [client 192.168.27.27:31458] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /webapp/hello, referer: https://frontend.example.com/webapp
```

While troubleshooting, I looked at at `netstat` output and noticed something possibly inconsequential but interesting nonetheless: Many connections to the backend had a `CLOSE_WAIT` status. All of these `CLOSE_WAIT` connections had `24` bytes listed in the `Recv-Q` column.

What could explain those 24 bytes not being pulled by Apache?

Comment: both sides agreed to tear down the TCP connection, but apparently Apache didn't bother to read the last few bytes beforehand (or the sending side sent bytes after the close that Apache wasn't expecting). You may need to capture them with tcpdump to determine which side is "misbehaving".

Comment: Are you aware of a way to view the queue itself?